# Speeding up iterations joining to df

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Stock stats data.

```
date        mkt_cap    income    sales   ...
2019-08-15    ###        ###      ###    ...
2019-08-16    ###        ###      ###    ...
...           ...        ...      ...    ...
```

This code takes a column from each stocks' stat file. Say "mkt_cap" and changes the header to the stock name then adds it to the main_df. Once the main_df has been populated with all stock's stats from the same sector it writes a new file "mkt_cap.csv", then continues onto the next stat and eventually the next sector.

```
def compile_sector_stats():
    for sector,name in zip(list_all_sectors, sector_names):
        main_df = pd.DataFrame()
        for item in items_averages:
            main_df = main_df[0:0]
            for value in sector:

                df = pd.read_csv('.../stocks/{}.csv'.format(value))
                df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
                df.rename(columns = {'{}'.format(item):'{}'.format(value)}, inplace=True)
                df.drop(df.columns.difference([value]),1,inplace=True)

                if main_df.empty:
                    main_df = df
                else:
                    main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')

        main_df.to_csv('.../sectors/{}/{}.csv'.format(name,item))
```

This code works perfectly but it starts to slow down ALOT when the main_df gets big. Each sector actually has 500-700 stocks. Is there a way to make this process faster or am I just going to have to make the sector lists smaller?

EDIT:

The ouput CSV file is supposed to look like the following for each stat:

```
mkt_cap.csv

date        stock1  stock2  stock 3 ...
2019-08-15   ###      ###    ###
2019-08-16   ###      ###    ###
...          ...      ...    ...
```

Comment: Hi @johnboy, it would be helpful if you could s provide a look into what the output should look like, so people can provide ideas on faster procedures.

Comment: Instead of iteratively joining new df to main_df, could you just collect a list of such new df's and then do pd.concat?

Comment: Do you mean append to a list? Thats actually an interesting idea.and worth a shot.

Comment: @johnboy Yes add all dataframe to a list and give that list to concat function, it will reduce time. Still if you want to reduce the time then you can use multiprocessing to generate each dataframe.